# Returning data from controllers to views in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to return a complex type from a controller to a view in asp.net mvc? All the examples I have looked at so far demonstrate passing simple intrinsic types like int, string....

Answer (score 2):

You can pass any object type to the view using the ViewData Dictionary.

Just put in your controller:

```
ViewData["example"] = (YourObject)data;
```

And then in your view:

```
<%= ((YourObject)ViewData["example"]).YourProperty %>
```

And if you want to pass your object as your View model then:

```
return View("viewname", (YourObject)data);
```

And make sure your view looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<YourObject>" %>
```

Comment: Why use ViewData when the YourObject already exists in the view as the Model?

Comment: i was trying to say that he can either pass the object using the viewdata or directly as the view model. My answer was very poor i admit.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a viewmodel that's then used in the strongly typed view. You can check out this [blogpost by Stephen Walther](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/04/13/asp.net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx) that explains it. I started out just dumping stuff in viewdata, but that gets confusing pretty quickly ;).

Answer (score 0):

Use a ViewModel for your page.

you could use a view model containing both complex and simple objects, for example:

```
public class MyComplexViewModel
{
    public Address UserAddress { get; set;}
    public List<string> ValidZipCodes { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

If your view inherits the generic ViewPage with something like this

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyComplexViewModel>" %>
```

you could then in the view use the view model as Model.:

```
<%= Html.Encode(Model.UserAddress.SomeAddressProperty) %>
<%= Html.Encode(Model.ValidZipCodes.Count) %>
<%= Html.Encode(Model.Message) %>
```